# Vectors in Clifford Algebra

Tags: clifford-algebras

I'm studying Clifford Algebra $\mathcal{Cl}_2$ and got stuck in an exercise:

Let $\mathbf{a}=e_2+e_{12},\quad \mathbf{b}=(1/2)(1+e_1).$ Compute $\mathbf{ab}$.

The answer is zero, but I can't get to it and I'm having trouble putting $\mathbf{b}$ in the form $\mathbf{b}=b_1e_1+b_2e_2$.

Important information:

- $(1, e_1, e_2, e_{12})$ form a basis for the Clifford algebra $\mathcal{Cl}_2$
- The Clifford product of two vectors $\mathbf{a}=a_1e_1+a_2e_2\text{ and }\mathbf{b}=b_1e_1+b_2e_2$ is defined as $\mathbf{ab}=a_1b_1+a_2b_2+(a_1b_2-a_2b_1)e_{12}$
- And the following multiplication table:
  $$
  \begin{array}{cccc}
    & \mathbf{e_1} & \mathbf{e_2} & \mathbf{e_{12}} \\\\
    \mathbf{e_1}& 1 & e_{12} & e_2 \\\\
    \mathbf{e_2}& -e_{12} & 1 & -e_1 \\\\
    \mathbf{e_{12}}& -e_2 & e_1 & -1
  \end{array}
  $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
2{\bf a}{\bf b} &=& (e_2+e_{12})(1+e_1) \\
&=& e_2+e_{12}+e_2 e_1+e_{12}e_1 \\
&=& e_2 + e_{12} +(-e_{12}) + (-e_2) \\
&=& 0
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: I see what you did, but shouldn't I put **b** as combination of e1, e2 and then use the Clifford product definition? I mean, can I do that multiplication so directly?
p.s.: sorry if it's a silly question,

Comment: @FernandoH.M.Bastos: Not a problem. What makes you think you can write ${\bf b}$ in terms of $e_1$ and $e_2$?

Comment: Actually, that was my main issue, cause I couldn't. In a previous execise I could put a vector c=(1+e2) in the form c=c1e1, with c1=(e1+e12), and got to the right answer so thought I should do it everytime. That previous result was just luck or there is any restriciton in this case of b?

Comment: @FernandoH.M.Bastos: The space is spanned by the linearly independent set $\{1,e_1,e_2,e_{12}\}$. By linear independence, you can't write any of the basis elements as a linear combination of the others. Think of it as trying to write $\hat z$ as a linear combination of $\hat x$ and $\hat y$.

Comment: Your last comment made everything clear, thanks a lot!

Comment: @FernandoH.M.Bastos: Glad to help. Cheers!